# WPF: Join Images in a Single File

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, image, serialization

My name's Lucas and I'm learning about WPF/C#.

I would like to join several images in a single file, as well as a game that use multiple textures that are all in one file, but I have no idea how to do. Could anyone help me at least to think how to do?

```
//Convert Image to Byte[]

    public byte[] getByteFromImage()
        {
            byte[] imageArray = File.ReadAllBytes(op.FileName);
            return imageArray;
        }

//Convert Byte[] to Image

        public void getImageFromByte()
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream("escudos.bcf", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(f);

            Int64 c = f.Length+1;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b.ReadBytes(int.Parse(c.ToString())));
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                      BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

            imgPatch2.Source = image.Source;
            f.Dispose();
        }

//Create Binary File

        public void save(byte[] img)
        {
            FileStream f;

            if (!File.Exists("escudos.bcf"))
            {
                f = new FileStream("escudos.bcf", FileMode.Create);
            }

            else
            {
                f = new FileStream("escudos.bcf", FileMode.Append);
            }

            BinaryWriter b = new BinaryWriter(f);
            b.Write(img);
            b.Close();
            f.Dispose();
        }
```

I thought in doing so, create a file and store it in binary images. 
Until I got that part, but as this file will have multiple images in binary, I do not know how to pick just one binary image.

```
public void xmlCreate(string name, Int64 ini, Int64 fin)
        {
            if (!File.Exists("Escudos.xml")) 
            {
                XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter("Escudos.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                w.WriteStartDocument();

                w.WriteStartElement("Time");
                w.WriteStartElement(name);
                w.WriteElementString("Inicio", ini.ToString());
                w.WriteElementString("Fim", fin.ToString());
                w.WriteEndElement();
                w.WriteEndDocument();

                w.Close();
            }

            else
            {


                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Escudos.xml");
                doc.Root.Add(new XElement(name));
                doc.Root.Element(name).Add(new XElement("Inicio", ini.ToString()));
                doc.Root.Element(name).Add(new XElement("Fim", fin.ToString()));
                doc.Save("Escudos.xml");


            }
        }
```

Now I have created an xml file to store the start and end of the bytes. I can add only when I create a new xml file, I can not get a xml created and add new bytes. When I go to load the xml file gives an error message.

*" An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 3, position 15. "*

---

**UPDATE**

when I'm reading the bytes to form an image, always the same way, even I adding different images. I'll add code below

```
//Add Image

private void btAddImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.Title = "Selecione a Imagem";
            op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";

            if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                imgPatch.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
                txtName.Focus();
            }
        }


//Convert Image

 private void btConvertImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
            {
                txtName.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha o Nome", "Error");
            }

            else
            {
                save(ConvertFileToByteArray(op.FileName), txtName.Text);
            }
        }

//Image to Byte Array

private static byte[] ConvertFileToByteArray(String FilePath)
        {
            return File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        }


//Save Binary File and XML File

public void save(byte[] img, string nome)
        {
            FileStream f;
            long ini, fin = img.Length; 

            if (!File.Exists("Escudos.bcf"))
            {
                f = new FileStream("Escudos.bcf", FileMode.Create);
                ini = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                f = new FileStream("Escudos.bcf", FileMode.Append);
                ini = f.Length + 1;
                bin = new TestBinarySegment();

            }

            bin.LoadAddSave("Escudos.xml", "Brasileiro", nome, ini, fin);



            BinaryWriter b = new BinaryWriter(f);
            b.Write(img);
            b.Close();
            f.Dispose();



        }


//Load Image from Byte
private void btLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            getImageFromByte();
        }


//Byte to Image
public void getImageFromByte(int start, int length)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Escudos.bcf", FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] iba = new byte[fs.Length+1];
                fs.Read(iba, start, length);
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                          BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

                imgPatch2.Source = image.Source;
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I see the problem, you need an XML data file to store a Rect structure for each image.

Comment: so I need to create a xml data file to store the binary codes?

Comment: No, you need to store the x,y location of each individual image that is inside the binary file.

Comment: from what I understand, the xml file I use to know that an image goes from byte 0 to byte 100, another image from byte 101 to 200, that?

Comment: yes, exactly.  you store the locations and use them to extract the files

Comment: Most developers would store all the images in a very large image, so that the extraction process goes quickly.

Comment: how so? an image with multiple images together?

Comment: Now I have created an xml file to store the start and end of the bytes. I can add only when I create a new xml file, I can not get a xml created and add new bytes. When I go to load the xml file gives an error message. Added xml code

Comment: what do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Now I have created an xml file to store the start and end of the bytes. I can add only when I create a new xml file, I can not get a xml created and add new bytes. When I go to load the xml file gives an error message.

" An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll Additional information: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 3, position 15. "

Comment: I use .NET serialization instead of what you use.  I can put in an answer like that if you think it will help.  It lets you add and save, but you will have to learn the theory also.

Comment: ok, if you can show me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a binary file where its contents are segments and each segment contains the binary information needed to create an image.  You need to store the starting index and length of each segment so that you can retrieve it.  One way to do this is with an xml file.

To begin, create a container class for the segments.  It looks like this...

```
public class BinarySegment
{
    private const string FileName = "SegmentData.xml";
    private static XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BinarySegment>));
    public string SegmentName { get; set; }
    public long SegmentStartIndex { get; set; }
    public long SegmentLength { get; set; }
    public static List<BinarySegment> LoadFromFile()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            throw new Exception("File must be created first");
        }
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize(sr) as List<BinarySegment>;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("File as become corrupted");
        }
    }
    public static void Save(List<BinarySegment> list)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, list);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

There is one instance of this class for each image in your binary file.  It will read/write a List of BinarySegments.

To test the class, create a test class like this...

```
public class TestBinarySegment
{
    public TestBinarySegment()
    {
        List<BinarySegment> myBinarySegments = new List<BinarySegment>();
        myBinarySegments.Add(new BinarySegment{SegmentName = "Segment1", SegmentStartIndex = 0, SegmentLength = 1111});
        myBinarySegments.Add(new BinarySegment { SegmentName = "Segment2", SegmentStartIndex = 1111, SegmentLength = 1111 });
        myBinarySegments.Add(new BinarySegment { SegmentName = "Segment3", SegmentStartIndex = 2222, SegmentLength = 1111 });
        BinarySegment.Save(myBinarySegments);
    }
    public void LoadAddSave()
    {
        List<BinarySegment> myBinarySegments = BinarySegment.LoadFromFile();
        myBinarySegments.Add(new BinarySegment { SegmentName = "Segment4", SegmentStartIndex = 333330, SegmentLength = 1111 });
        BinarySegment.Save(myBinarySegments);
    }
}
```

This class shows how to create the list and to save it.  It also shows how to add new segments and resave the xml file.

When the test is run, you get a file like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBinarySegment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <BinarySegment>
    <SegmentName>Segment1</SegmentName>
    <SegmentStartIndex>0</SegmentStartIndex>
    <SegmentLength>1111</SegmentLength>
  </BinarySegment>
  <BinarySegment>
    <SegmentName>Segment2</SegmentName>
    <SegmentStartIndex>1111</SegmentStartIndex>
    <SegmentLength>1111</SegmentLength>
  </BinarySegment>
  <BinarySegment>
    <SegmentName>Segment3</SegmentName>
    <SegmentStartIndex>2222</SegmentStartIndex>
    <SegmentLength>1111</SegmentLength>
  </BinarySegment>
  <BinarySegment>
    <SegmentName>Segment4</SegmentName>
    <SegmentStartIndex>333330</SegmentStartIndex>
    <SegmentLength>1111</SegmentLength>
  </BinarySegment>
</ArrayOfBinarySegment>
```

To run the test, use code like this...

```
        TestBinarySegment test = new TestBinarySegment();
        test.LoadAddSave();
```

This shows how to use xml serialization to create a file and add new segments to it.  You will need to test this concept and then integrate it into your project.

Comment: Very good, I understood and could apply códio, thanks! 

But I wonder if it is possible mustar at the beginning of the document "ArrayOfBinarySegment" element. The word BinarySegment renaming is possible to change the class, but what ArrayOf?

Comment: I've got it, thanks, now I'll try to implement its part to separate the bytes of the generated file

Comment: Ok, I marked as answer, if I have any questions I comment, thank you :)

Comment: @LucasGuitar I editted the tags on your question to include xml and serialization.  They are a better fit.

Comment: when I'm reading the bytes to form an image, always the same way, even I adding different images. I'll add code below

Comment: It is way better to add a new question.  Nobody is looking at this one any more.  Make a new question with the new code etc

Comment: also, I do it differently; my binary is a huge image where I pluck out the file based on x/y coordinates inside the big image.  See https://www.dropbox.com/s/4awutx3d07418ac/Flowers.jpg